# How do I run webpack from SBT

Tags: playframework, sbt, webpack

I'm developing a Play 2.4 application and would like SBT to run webpack to generate static assets during compilation.

I tried https://github.com/stejskal/sbt-webpack but it does't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I managed to have it work by defining a custom sbt task that is used a dependence for `dist` and `stage` tasks invoked when you package your application.

The code of the task is straight forward :

```scala
lazy val webpack = taskKey[Unit]("Run webpack when packaging the application")

  def runWebpack(file: File) = {
    Process("webpack", file) !
  }

  webpack := {
    if(runWebpack(baseDirectory.value) != 0) throw new Exception("Something goes wrong when running webpack.")
  }

  dist <<= dist dependsOn webpack

  stage <<= stage dependsOn webpack
```

In dev mode I use [play action hooks](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SBTCookbook#Hook-actions-around-play-run) to run `webpack watch` when the code changes :

```scala
PlayKeys.playRunHooks <+= baseDirectory.map(Webpack.apply)
```

with `Webpack`defined as follows :

```scala
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import play.sbt.PlayRunHook
import sbt._

object Webpack {
  def apply(base: File): PlayRunHook = {
    object WebpackHook extends PlayRunHook {
      var process: Option[Process] = None

      override def beforeStarted() = {
        process = Option(
          Process("webpack", base).run()
        )
      }

      override def afterStarted(addr: InetSocketAddress) = {
        process = Option(
          Process("webpack --watch", base).run()
        )
      }

      override def afterStopped() = {
        process.foreach(_.destroy())
        process = None
      }
    }

    WebpackHook
  }
}
```

It works like a charm. You find at my github account a sample play project using this technique : https://github.com/nouhoum/play-react-webpack/blob/master/webpack.sbt

I hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Nouhoum's answer was working fine until I updated to SBT 1.0.x

Just a few updates were needed:

```scala
import scala.sys.process.Process

lazy val webpack = taskKey[Unit]("Run webpack when packaging the application")

def runWebpack(file: File) = {
  Process("npm run build", file) !
}

webpack := {
  if(runWebpack(baseDirectory.value) != 0) throw new Exception("Something went wrong when running webpack.")
}

dist := (dist dependsOn webpack).value

stage := (stage dependsOn webpack).value
```

Answer (score 2):

We've built `sbt-webpack` that integrates cleanly with the incremental compilation with Playframework's static assets. I hope that what you want. It works as expected with `sbt run` and `sbt stage`.

At [GIVE.asia](https://give.asia),  We are using it for packaging `Vue`, `Axios`, and `Vue-i18` into a single JS file, which is later included in our HTML file. Then, we use `expose-loader` to expose the variables `Vue`, `VueI18n`, and `axios`.

The reason to prefer `sbt-webpack` is that it generates the output file to an appropriate location that can be used by Playframework's routing. Because it integrates with the incremental compilation with Playframework's static assets.

Here's the repo: https://github.com/GIVESocialMovement/sbt-webpack

Or you can jump directly to a working example: https://github.com/GIVESocialMovement/sbt-webpack/tree/master/test-play-project

Comment: Your plugin gives dependency not found.. I added an issue over the github repo

Comment: Thank you for trying it. I think the root cause is the mismatch of either sbt version of scala's major version. I've replied in the github issue. Let's sort this out.